# Flask: deleting file in @after_this_request decorator not working. File it is being used by another process

Tags: javascript, python, flask, request

Hi i want to download a zip file and then delete it after the download has finished.

```
@app.route('/download',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download():
    projectTitle = request.args.get('projectTitle')
    file_path = projectTitle+".zip"

    @after_this_request
    def remove_file(response):
        print("After this request...")
        os.remove(file_path)
        return response

    return send_file(file_path,
                 mimetype='application/zip',
                 attachment_filename=file_path,
                 as_attachment=True)
```

I call this endpoint with javascript:

```
function downloadURI(uri) 
{
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = uri;
    link.target = "_blank";
    link.click();
}

downloadURI("download?projectTitle="+title);
```

The zip file never gets deleted, what am I missing?
**EDIT:** I debugged a little and I noticed I'm getting the following error:

```
After this request...
After this request...
[2020-07-10 13:00:40,653] ERROR in app: Exception on /download [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1970, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2267, in process_response
    response = handler(response)
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/SingleBP/app.py", line 39, in remove_file
    os.remove(file_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'DemoTMD-prod.zip'
[2020-07-10 13:00:40,656] ERROR in app: Request finalizing failed with an error while handling an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1970, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2267, in process_response
    response = handler(response)
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/SingleBP/app.py", line 39, in remove_file
    os.remove(file_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'DemoTMD-prod.zip'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1970, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\PycharmProjects\SingleBP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2267, in process_response
    response = handler(response)
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/SingleBP/app.py", line 39, in remove_file
    os.remove(file_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'DemoTMD-prod.zip'
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2020 13:00:40] "GET /download?projectTitle=DemoTMD-prod HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

As you see @after_this_request is called (I don't know why) two times, in fact "After this request" is printed two times.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, when the `@after_this_request` decorated method called, this request life has not end, and the client still wait for response, so the file is still opening, or you can say it is being used, so you can't delete the file.

Well, this is my solution. Just like:

```py
from stuff import celery_app


@celery_app.task(queue='some_specific_queue')
def delete_files(filepath):
    try:
        os.remove(filepath)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # some other stuff
```

And in you api, you can publish this task like：

```py
import datetime


@app.route('/download',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download():
    projectTitle = request.args.get('projectTitle')
    file_path = projectTitle+".zip"

    delete_files.apply_async(
        args=(file_path), 
        eta=datetime.datetime.utcnow()+datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
    )

    return send_file(file_path,
                 mimetype='application/zip',
                 attachment_filename=file_path,
                 as_attachment=True)
```

I don't know how to at people...